# Scanning 3D with a Kinect v2 on AMD Ryzen 7?

Tags: scanning

My processor is running at 4.70 GHz and has 8 cores.  I also have 32GB RAM. I have a USB 3.0 and a USB 3.1 xHCI hub, and Nvidia 1700 graphics card.

Can I use the Kinect v2 and the adapter to scan rooms, and objects, quickly, without trouble with the USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short with the hardware you have it should be no problem. In actuality your specific setup, how you move the scanner, how stable is the scanner, what software you are using, and how you've calibrated the kinect will most likely have the largest impact on the quality, and speed in which you can scan.

Comment: I use fuse and kinect v2 for xbox with the adapter. How do i calibrate the kinect?

Comment: It will most likely be somewhere in the settings of whatever software you are using to scan.